# Angular12 How to combine ng-zorro-antd calendar with External Event Dragging?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, draggable, ng-zorro-antd

I am using `ng-zorro-antd` 12.0.1 in my Angular 12 projects, I need to implement the requirement that user could drag events to the [ant design calendar](https://ng.ant.design/components/calendar/en),

I could make it by using full-calendar from here :

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging

but I  have no idea how to extend it on the ant design and it seems that there are no settings for me to do that.

Comment: From https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/6957 , it is not supported now